# What are some ways to save major amounts of power on Desktop Computer?

Tags: power, mode

What are some ways to save major amounts of power on Desktop Computer? Also, I have a question about the Minimum and Maximum processor state. If I set both Minimum and Maximum processor state to 0 percent, will this help save power or no?

Obviously, I understand that the effects of setting them to both 0 percent would slow down the computer majorly, but will it be effective in saving power?

If you know of any software that could further help me save power use from a Desktop Computer, please share them with me.

Does limiting RAM usage within msconfig help to save any power?

Comment: Well one way to save a lot of power is to turn it off.

Comment: I turn it off instantly when I am not using it. I am talking about when I am using it.

Comment: It would help to know what your computer is made up of?? Like a GPU can be locked down to a lower clock for both memory and processing speed, to save quite a bit of power. Turning off many windows speeder uppers and pre-doing things can save power. Using classic desktop save minor power. Limiting ram could reduce some power use, ram has to be continually kept alive and refreshed (even if unused) , but high usage of it (not just stuff parked in it) increases consumption and heat. SSD certannly use less power, and waking up faster means they can also sleep without long wake times.

Comment: Stopping the processor from stepping fully, will save power in the newer intel type systems because the voltage itself also steps down as needed (much less power used again). There probably still exists a balance here in taking many times longer to accomplish anything. The cpu itself would (still) be using less power, the rest of the machine still used much power while waiting for the processor to finish something so slowly.

Comment: Mainly having an efficient power supply.  Then you want to have your hard drives set to turn off when not used for a few minutes.  And of course the display is a major power user, so you want an efficient one and want it to go black when not used for a few minutes.  To do much more you have to replace the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to save power,many of which depend on your usage pattern.

If the PC needs to be on all the time, a platinum rated PSU will save money after a certain time period (initial cost recovered in a year for example). It will reduce your power anyway, but it just wont pay for itself in a short time if the PC isn't always on.

Turning the processor usage to 0% is actually likely to use more power overall. Because the processor is using (lets say) 25w instead of 50w for twice as long, it would seem an equal amount of power is used. However, for that time period, your speakers, monitor, HDDs, RAM, and literally everything else is running too, so you actually go from 200w for 10 seconds to 225w for 5 seconds. Leave maximum CPU on 100%, minimum on 0%. Note that there can be exceptions to this rule.

Disconnecting hardware from your PC can work (like a TV capture card that isn't being used).

Replace a HDD with an SSD for speed gains and power reduction. Probably not cost effective just for power issues though.

Only use one monitor (if you have two) when you only need one.

open msconfig (winkey+R, type 'msconfig' without quotes), and turn off everything that isn't needed in the startup tab. Note that you may stop things from working if you don't know what your doing; but if you experiment, you'll learn. This can stop some programs from constantly waking up the CPU from idle to do 'stuff'.

You can also buy a watt-meter to measure your power usage, and see what effects different settings have.